# Box2D in Java application

Tags: java, jar, box2d

I want to use box2d.jar as a library in my Java application .
I have copied it from one of my LibGDX projects and added that jar in the libraries of the application . But now I am getting this error .

```
Exception in thread "Thread-0" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at com.marimba.space.PhysX.<init>(PhysX.java:40)
    at com.marimba.space.Room.<init>(Room.java:14)
    at com.marimba.space.Main$1.run(Main.java:62)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: com.badlogic.gdx.utils.GdxRuntimeException: Couldn't load shared library 'gdx-box2d.dll' for target: Windows 7, 32-bit
    at com.badlogic.gdx.utils.SharedLibraryLoader.load(SharedLibraryLoader.java:117)
    at com.badlogic.gdx.physics.box2d.World.<clinit>(World.java:187)
    ... 4 more
Caused by: com.badlogic.gdx.utils.GdxRuntimeException: Unable to read file for extraction: gdx-box2d.dll
    at com.badlogic.gdx.utils.SharedLibraryLoader.readFile(SharedLibraryLoader.java:126)
    at com.badlogic.gdx.utils.SharedLibraryLoader.loadFile(SharedLibraryLoader.java:261)
    at com.badlogic.gdx.utils.SharedLibraryLoader.load(SharedLibraryLoader.java:115)
    ... 5 more
```

Any ideas how can I fix this? Or how can I use box2D in my Java application?

I tried [jbox2d.jar](http://www.jbox2d.org/) but that doesn`t contain all the classes of box2d.

Comment: Do you use any engine in your app? they sometimes have box2d extensions. Consider andEngine and its box2d extension.

Comment: I have copied that jar file from libGDX project(libGDX is game engine).But I dont use any engine , it is Java Application